# Diferencia de tiempo entre dos DateTime C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime

Tengo un registro en mi base de datos el cual me guarda la fecha y hora en este formato, el campo es `Datetime`:

```
2020-03-04 15:12:08.540
```

Ahora bien, desde C# obtengo ese campo mediante un `query` y lo asigno a una variable de tipo `DateTime`.

Tengo declarada otra variable para obtener el `datetime` actual para compararlo con el de la base de datos y así obtener la diferencia trasncurrida en minutos del último registro contra el nuevo registro que intento realizar.

```
 DateTime CompFch;
 DateTime fchNow = DateTime.Now;//fecha y hora actual
 if (reader.Read())
            {
                CompFch = reader.GetDateTime(0);//obtengo y asigno la fecha de la dB a mi variable
                TimeSpan result = fchNow.Subtract(CompFch).Duration();
                string val = Convert.ToString(result.Minutes);//aqui obtengo los minutos transcurridos
                if (Convert.ToInt32(val) <= 5)//
                {
                    return "Ya está registrado.";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
```

Por ejemplo, tengo esa fecha de registro, pero lo comparo con la fecha de hoy y solo me dice que han transcurido a lo mucho 15 min, osea eso esta mal, deberían ser muchos más minutos porque ya transcurrió un día.

Mi idea es si ya está registrado y si intenté registrar otra vez en ese mismo instante, pero no han trasncurrido 5 minutos desde su primer registro entonces retorna "Ya esta registrado.".

Debe pasar por lo menos 5 minutos para que pueda volver a registrar.

Comment: Estas comprobando `TimeSpan.Minutes`. Prueba con `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`

Comment: si eso era, pequeno detalle pero ya me estaba calando.

Comment: ponlo como respuesta para marcarlo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás comprobando la propiedad [`TimeSpan.Minutes`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timespan.minutes?view=netframework-4.8):

> Obtiene el componente de minutos del intervalo de tiempo representado por la estructura TimeSpan actual. El valor devuelto está comprendido entre -59 y 59.

Para comprobar el total de minutos de un `TimeSpan` debes comprobar la propiedad [`TimeSpan.TotalMinutes`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.timespan.totalminutes?view=netframework-4.8):

> Obtiene el valor de la estructura TimeSpan actual, expresado en minutos completos y fracciones de minutos.

```
string val = Convert.ToString(result.TotalMinutes);
```