# ¿como calcular la cantidad de minutos que hay entre dos fechas? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Necesito calcular la cantidad de minutos totales que hay entre dos fechas. POR EJEMPLO. 
la variable FechaHoraInicio es {22/05/2020 0:00:00},
la variable FechaHoraTermino es {23/05/2020 11:00:00}
sacando cuentas, yo veo que hay 23 horas de diferencia!! osea 1380 minutos.

PERO el "timespan diferencia "me trae 1:11:00:00, que serian 1 dia/11 minutos.
y si paso eso a minutos serian 2100 minutos totales !! Entonces nose como hacer para calcular los minutos totales AYUDAA

```
string FechaHora1 = cInicio.Text + ' ' + HoraInicio.Text;
DateTime FechaHoraInicio = DateTime.Parse(FechaHora1);
string FechaHora2 = cfin.Text + ' ' + HoraTermino.Text;
DateTime FechaHoraTermino = DateTime.Parse(FechaHora2);

TimeSpan diferencia =  FechaHoraTermino - FechaHoraInicio;
var diferenciaenminutos = diferencia.TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Diferencia de tiempo entre dos DateTime C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/334734/diferencia-de-tiempo-entre-dos-datetime-c)

Answer (score 1):

Realmente hay 1 dia y 11 horas de diferencia.

Mira lo siguiente:

1. {22/05/2020 0:00:00}: 12am del dia 22 de Mayo. **[Inicio del dia]**
2. {23/05/2020 11:00:00}: 11pm del dia 23 de Mayo. **[Final del dia - 1 hora]**

Por lo tanto timespan te está dando la información correcta. Para obtener las 23 horas que esperabas, entonces las fechas deberían ser:

1. {22/05/2020 0:00:00}: 12am del dia 22 de Mayo. **[Inicio del dia]**
2. {22/05/2020 11:00:00}: 11pm del dia 22 de Mayo. **[Final del dia - 1 hora]**

Comment: Muchas gracias, todo este tiempo fue un error mio, gracias.

Comment: @LucianoSaavedra si esta respuesta te sirvió para resolver el problema. Considera marcarla como aceptada.